# How do you filter WikiVoyage API results by city?

Tags: php, api, wiki, mediawiki-api

I'm currently in the process of trying to use the wikivoyage API.  My current API call looks like:

```
en.wikivoyage.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srwhat=text&srsearch=Pari&format=json
```

I can't figure out how to filter my results by city.  I can't figure out which parameter to use. These are the two pieces of documentation I am trying to sift through.

http://en.wikivoyage.org/w/api.php

http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Special%3aApiSandbox

Comment: MediaWiki has no concept of cities.
You may want to research Wikidata.

Comment: In this sense, even if it doesn't answer your question directly, [here is](https://frama.link/uT_ZWZtK) how to get all English wikivoyage pages that concern cities, using Wikidata site links. Please specify your question so that we can precisely answer you : for example, how do you want to select these cities ? Using their name only ?